# I can't set my reference numbers's format to "byte" or "short" in console project?

Tags: c#, console

Actually this is my first question on this site and i hope it's right way to ask this type question.

I'm just learning C# from scratch in Youtube.

I created simple console project that has multiply function as you can see below, but I can't set my reference numbers (number1, number2) to "short" or "byte". But I can set them "long", "decimal" "int" etc.

I did little search and I have theory that this is about bits and bytes counts of each parameter but can't really comprehend the concept.

May anyone explain this error that I'm encountering with simple language any chance? Thanks for any explanation :)

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Start:
            int number1;
            int number2;

            Console.Write("enter number to multiply:");
            number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("enter another number:");
            number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("the result is:" + number1 * number2 + "(" + number1 + "X" + number2 + ")");
            Console.WriteLine();
            goto Start;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hey silly! that's not even a number:)");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question because I couldn't clearly understand it. can you include the error you got when you tried to set your `number1` to `byte` or `short`? Moreover, just a hint: Don't use `goto`, just put your whole code in a loop instead.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will check for loop. If I set them byte or short, Visual Studio can't compile them and says "there were build errors."

Comment: What errors are you getting when declaring those variables as short or byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track; it's about implicit conversion of types and strong typing.

Not to overload you with all the details, you can make some adjustments for

#### short:

*note the `ToInt16`*

```
short number1;
//etc
number1 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
```

#### byte:

*note: the `ToByte`*

```
byte number1;
//etc
number1 = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
```

#### long

> left as an exercise

---

Crucial is that, although all the types consists of bits, and are basically numbers, C# want to be sure you mean what you are saying and enforces you to use the correct `type`.

---

So, why does it work for `decimal` etc.?

Is because C# thinks it's valid to [implicitly convert them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table), and therefor the compiler is doing it for you.

In the link you can see that for `int` (aka `Int32`) the folowing implicit conversions are predefined:

```
//from  |  to
//int   |  long, float, double, or decimal
```

In the linked table you can also see that the other way round, from `byte` to `int` is allowed.

---

The big lesson: C# is strong typed: if you say it's an Int16 (aka short), you must use it only as an `Int16` (and not an `Int32`)

Happy coding ;-)

Comment: Thanks Stefan! That link helped me a lot to understand my struggle and ToInt16 solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your problem - in order to "set" a variable to a given type you will need to declare it as such before compiling (before the program run).

So if you want to work with long numbers you will need to declare:

```
long number1;
long number2;
```

Your conversions should reflect it:

```
number1 = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
```

For decimal

```
decimal number1;
decimal number2;
```

Conversion e.g. decimal.parse(number1).

For byte

```
byte number1;
byte number2;
```

Again your conversion must enforced per each type.

Just a note. Using a goto is something that I don't approve neither suggest. Learn to use a loop. If those videos are using the goto, I would advise to learn from a better source.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I solved with using ToInt16 and stopped using "goto" :)

Comment: Good stuff. Happy coding :-)